# Displaying Vinculum(symbol) in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Is there a way to display a vinculum(symbol) in Android Studio? I am trying to get my numbers to look like this

[image]

I have looked around forever now and I am just hitting a wall, any help is greatly appreciated.

If this is a possibility I would appreciate any code suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: Text decorations like that are usually done with spans. Oddly, there doesn't seem to be one that lets us easily draw just whatever we want, by just passing a `Canvas` and some coordinates, so this is kind of abusing a `ReplacementSpan`, which is for substituting things like images for text: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A6WMVto1_RA0tt-Lik4MmMZks79jC5ZN/view?usp=drivesdk. I didn't do any thorough testing, but you might give it a try. You may have to tweak the line coordinates and thickness to your liking. It doesn't work with overlapping spans, as is, but it should work for the example.